# Programmatically edit the text of a widget

Tags: widgets

I have text widgets that contain text. I'd like to programmatically edit that text.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How do you want to identify target widget for starters?

Comment: @Rarst, By any means necessary, really. It'd be nice to do it by widget name, i.e. "Homepage Left Widget."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want to locate the widget by it's title, so you can try this function:

```
/**
 * Update a widget text located by it's title
 * 
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155518/26350
 *
 * @param string $search_title
 * @param string $new_text
 * @param boolean
 */

function wpse_155046_update_widget_text_by_title( $search_title, $new_text )
{
    // Get all data from text widgets 
    $widgets = get_option( 'widget_text' );

    foreach( $widgets as $key => $widget )
    {       
        // Compare and ignore case:
        if( mb_strtolower( $search_title ) === mb_strtolower( $widget['title'] ) )
        {
            // Replace the widget text:
            $widgets[$key]['text'] = $new_text;

            // Update database and exit on first found match:
            return update_option( 'widget_text', $widgets );
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

where we only replace the text of the first widget instance that matches the given title.

### Usage example:

You can apply the above function like demonstrated here:

```
if( wpse_155046_update_widget_text_by_title( 
        'My fruits', 
        'Five green apples and nine oranges.' 
     ) 
)
{
    echo 'success';
}
else
{
    echo 'no success';
}
```

where we replace the text of the widget with the title *My fruits*.

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

You can also check out [my answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/147326/26350) on where the widget data is located in the database.

### Update:

A good question from @Tony in the comments below, how one could replace the widget text given the instance number. Here's an untested idea:

```
/**
 * Update a widget text located by it's instance number
 * 
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155518/26350
 *
 * @param string $id
 * @param string $new_text
 * @param boolean
 */

function wpse_155046_update_widget_text_by_instance_number( $instance_number, $new_text )
{
    // Get all data from text widgets 
    $widgets = get_option( 'widget_text' );

    if( isset( $widgets[$instance_number]['text'] ) ) 
    {
        // Replace the widget text:
        $widgets[$instance_number]['text'] = $new_text;

        // Update database and exit on first found match:
        return update_option( 'widget_text', $widgets );
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: thanks @birgire for your helpful answer but how i can search for that widget by it's id instead of it's title?

Comment: @Tony I guess you mean the instance number, I updated the answer. Hopefully it helps.